# How to use promise when adding if condition on .then?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I don't know much about promises. I would like to trigger my function `failresponse` when a condition is met. `failresponse` shows a text error on the user screen. And, if it's possible, I would like to avoid triggering the function `getDataPDV`. How should I resolve it? The `else` code is correct and it works.

Thank you.

```
    if (nomProduit,pdvType,classeProduit,sousClasseProduit == "") {
        geoCode(location).then(function(locationFromApi) {
          getDataPDV(locationFromApi, pdvType, nomProduit, classeProduit, sousClasseProduit)
          .then(() => failResponse(res, requestBody.text));
        });
    } else {      
        geoCode(location).then(function(locationFromApi) {
        getDataPDV(locationFromApi, pdvType, nomProduit, classeProduit, sousClasseProduit)
        .then(function(data) {
          return successResponsev2(res, data);
        })
        .catch(() => failResponse(res, requestBody.text));
      });
    }
```

Comment: Don't call `dataPDV` ?

Comment: I tried to remove all in if condition and just trigger "failresponse" but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: In the catch, you have to work with error, that function can not "see" response `res` from outside of its scope.

Comment: You should return getDataPDV in both statements. Otherwise, you create a promise inside a promise. Always return (or `resolve()`) to chain different `.then`'s together.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise actually explains promises really well, if you take the time to dissect the examples. That's how I managed to handle promises. That ... and failing a lot to put the pieces together. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I find, let me know if it helps

```
geoCode(location).then((locationFromApi) => {

    getDataPDV(locationFromApi, pdvType, nomProduit, classeProduit, sousClasseProduit).then((data) => {

        if(nomProduit && pdvType && classeProduit && sousClasseProduit){
            failResponse(res, requestBody.text);
        }
        else{
            successResponsev2(res, data);
        }

    };
}).catch(()=>{
    failResponse(res, requestBody.text)
});
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried something like that but i dont understand why it doesnt work. faileresponse is triggered in "catch" but not in "if" condition.

Comment: There can be two cases in which control will go to catch: 1. `geoCode(location)` is not resolving. 2. there is some error with code in **then** block of `geoCode(location)`.
Can you check your `geoCode` and `getDataPDV` I can guarantee that there may be some errors

Comment: Thx, it solved my problem.Case close. @Akshay Bande

Answer (score 0):

You appear to not be returning any data along after 
the second promise  is resolved

To avoid triggering the function,you could try having it like this

function (){
getDataPDV(locationFromApi, pdvType, nomProduit, classeProduit, sousClasseProduit
}

This will prevent the getDataPDV from being invoked automatically.